# Index was outside of the bounds of the array in C#

Tags: c#

I am getting an error , the error i am getting is Index was outside the bounds of the array.

My code is,

```
          try
          {

             string path = (string)(Application.StartupPath + "\\TEMP\\TEMP_BACKFILL_atoz" + "\\" + name_atoz);
             string reader1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
             string str = reader1;
             //reader1.Close();
             //reader1.Dispose();
             File.Delete(path);
             string[] Strarray = str.Split(new char[] { Strings.ChrW(10) });
             int abc = Strarray.Length - 2;
             int xyz = 0;
             bool status = true;

             string[] strarray1 = Strarray[xyz].Split(",".ToCharArray());//the line number 3696
             string SecName = strarray1[0];
             string SecSym = strarray1[1];
             int DT = int.Parse(strarray1[2]);
             int TM = int.Parse(strarray1[3]);
             float O = float.Parse(strarray1[4]);
             float H = float.Parse(strarray1[5]);
             float L = float.Parse(strarray1[6]);
             float C = float.Parse(strarray1[7]);
             double V = double.Parse(strarray1[8]);
             double OI = double.Parse(strarray1[9]);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
```

the StackTrace say that the    at Downloader.Form1.123_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) in C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\New Folder\Downloader\Downloader\Downloader\Downloader\Form1.cs:line 3696

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question, did you debug and do you know on what line this is happens ?

Comment: I am trying  to find pblm , but i am unable to find , thats why i asking  the help. because i am in new  c#

Comment: @guyl, scroll over to the right in the code block to see the comment about line 3696 where the error occurs.

Comment: you only process the first line of the file (there is no loop).

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] strarray1 = Strarray[xyz].Split(",".ToCharArray());//the line number 3696
```

since this line is throwing the error, and xyz = 0, we must assume that strarray1 is empty at this point.

As a general rule, unless you are 100% certain about what your array contains, you should always check it's length before trying to access an element.

Comment: Or: check the Length before throwing an exception.

Answer (score 0):

First point: Catching just the base class of the Exception object is never a very good idea, especially for debugging.
 Sometimes its better to let visual studio break at a error-point and then to examine the variables. You could then check the length of Strarray, which I assume will be 0.

Second point: You have a lot of useless variables, especially `int xyz = 0;`and `bool status = true;`
I would also like to mension that its very helpful to name the variables so that you can later tell what they are for. Names like "O" and "xyz" are totally useless and not helpful.

Now to your excact problem, `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path)` returns an array of strings, one item per line. You should change your
 `string reader1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);`

 to 
`string[] reader1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path);`

then you can change 
`string[] strarray1 = Strarray[xyz].Split(",".ToCharArray());`
to 
`string[] strarray1 = reader1[0].Split(",".ToCharArray());`

That should solve your problem, but you should learn for further work with C# to name your variables correctly and to keep your code clean. After 1 month you won't know what "a" and "xyz" were for, blieve me :-)

Comment: It may depend on the C# version but you don't need all those `ToCharArray()`s

Comment: @Henk Holterman then tell me a better way to convert the character ',' to a char array? Don't you think its easier to write ToCharArray that to write `new char[] { ',' }`?

Comment: I was thinking `s.Split(',')`

Comment: Yeah that would do in this case, but I thought the OP was going to keep the delimiters extendable, i.e. later doing `",.!".ToCharArray()`